# ArrayList addAll isn't adding elements

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am having an interesting problem I can't figure out. I have a simple ArrayList that holds the order of a playlist for my application. When someone clicks on a different song it needs to re-order the playlist. I am doing that elsewhere in the code. Then I call "setNewPlaylist" which clears the playlist and call addAll. The problem being, the incoming array list has 7 items in it, however after calling addAll, the playlist size is 0. It makes absolutely no sense and it's driving me a little nuts. I am hoping someone can help. Here is the relevant part of the code.. the part that's failing...

MusicLibrary...

```
public static final ArrayList<Long> playlist = new ArrayList<>();
//...

public static void setNewPlaylist(ArrayList<Long> newPlaylist) {
    Log.d("MusicLibrary", "Incoming playlist size is: " + newPlaylist.size());
    playlist.clear();
    playlist.addAll(newPlaylist);
    Log.d("MusicLibrary", "New playlist size is: " + playlist.size());
}
```

given that code I am getting this in the logs..

> D/MusicLibrary: Incoming playlist size is: 7
>                   New playlist size is: 0

How is that even possible? The incoming list has 7 items in it, I clear the static playlist then call addAll and it is 0 length? Please help me out here, it makes no sense and I am at a complete loss. Thank you.

I was wrong. I thought I was creating a new array list for newPlaylist but as it turns out I was using...

ArrayList newPlaylist = MusicLibrary.getPlaylist();

Which will just edit the playlist from MusicLibrary and not create a new array list.Coming from PHP it would make sense that newPlaylist is not the original playlist from MusicLibrary and editing it wouldn't change the reference to the actual playlist from MusicLibrary. I apologize. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure `newPlaylist` and `playlist` aren't in fact referencing the same `ArrayList`? Can you show the call site for `setNewPlaylist`?

Comment: I think this is not a [mcve], but making one would really help to solve the problem.

Comment: Is it possible both variables are pointing to the same concrete `ArrayList`? In such circumstances, calling `clear()` on `playlist` would clear the (single) list that both variables are referencing, and then the subsequent `addAll()` call would simply add an empty list to itself.

Comment: Are you sure new playlist is not pointing to playlist in any way? You can test this by printing the size of newPlaylist after playlist.clear()

Answer (score 4):

In fact it is enough simple to guess that the two lists refer the same object.

```
1. Log.d("MusicLibrary", "Incoming playlist size is: " + newPlaylist.size()); // 7
2. playlist.clear();
3. playlist.addAll(newPlaylist);
4. Log.d("MusicLibrary", "New playlist size is: " + playlist.size()); // 0
```

At the line 1 : `newPlaylist.size==7` and then you never invoke any method on the `newPlaylist` variable that could change the size of the object referenced.
So if `playlist.size()` at the line 4 is not `7` but `0`, it will necessary mean that `newPlaylist` elements were removed. And in this code the single thing that clear a list is : `playlist.clear()`.

---

You can check that by simulating the two cases (same object or two distinct objects).

If the variables refer two distinct objects you will get a size of `7` for `playlist`  :

```
newPlaylist.size() --> newPlaylist==7
playlist.clear(); --> playlist==0
playlist.addAll(newPlaylist); playlist==7
```

But if the variables refer the same object you will get a size of `0` for `playlist`  :

```
newPlaylist.size() --> newPlaylist==7, playlist==7
playlist.clear(); --> newPlaylist==0, playlist==0
playlist.addAll(newPlaylist); newPlaylist==0, playlist==0
```

You get the second result : `0`. So the two variables `List` refer the same object and `List.clear()` result is so reflected for both variables.